# Redirect to Page after Login (with variable)

Tags: redirect, home-url

I want to redirect subscribers to a special page after login to my WordPress Site ("http://www.my-cool-page.com/coolpeople") where "coolpeople" is a regular WordPress page. This is my code to redirect only the "subscribers":

```
$internStart = 'evenmorecoolpeople';
function loginRedirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && $user->has_cap( 'edit_posts' ) === false ) {
        echo 'return URL: ' . home_url('/') . $internStart; die ();
        return home_url();
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'loginRedirect', 10, 3 );
```

Now I want to replace "coolpeople" with a variable like:

```
$internStart = 'evenmorecoolpeople';
```

but ...

```
return home_url($internStart);
```

or ...

```
return home_url('/') . $internStart;
```

Does not work. Any Idea?

Comment: What do you get if, before `return home_url`, you put in the following code: `echo 'return URL: ' . home_url('/') . $internStart; die ();` ?

Comment: It brings me to "http://www.my-cool-page.com/wp-login.php" with a white page with only this content: `"return URL: http://www.my-cool-page.com/"`.

Comment: Perhaps show us all the whole `loginRedirect` function where you're trying to use the $internStart variable.

Comment: That's all. `$internStart = 'evenmorecoolpeople';` is just on top of the function (in "functions.php").

Comment: If you've put my `echo` line inside the brackets, before `return home_url`, but the redirect is still happening, then the `if` conditions are not being met. The line I gave you should output the URL that is being used for the redirect, and then should not redirect.

Comment: I edited the question, this is what I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51323/discussion-between-iguanarama-and-henning-fischer).

Comment: It is a [variable scope issue](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), test by putting a line with `global $internStart;` at the begin of your function.

Comment: @something, you are right, and even better is to not use global variables at all ;)

Comment: @MarkKaplun You're right too, but let's start with recognizing the problem first.

Comment: @something You were right, just clarified with OP in chat.

Comment: @iguanarama, the second comment indicates that it does get there

Comment: @iguanarama This - `echo 'return URL: ' . home_url('/') . $internStart; die ();` - doesn't make sense at all, just scrap it from the code.

Comment: @something it was to clarify what string was being built, as a test function, before he updated the function to show the variable he was using and its scope.

Comment: @iguanarama But it interrupts the process, so it has to be removed.

Comment: @something Yes you are right, it was just for testing to stop the redirect. :) It's all sorted now, the OP said in chat that the variable scope was the issue.

Comment: Yes this was the only issue, thanks for the help :)